# Count all characters, then print how many of which characters

Tags: python

In Python, I need to write a program that:

Asks the user to enter a string text.
It prints out, for every letter in text, how many times it occurs in text.
In the printout, letters should appear in the order in which they appear in the text, but no letter should appear twice.
For any letter, you should show the TOTAL number of times it shows up in either upper case or lower case (do not count or display upper and lower cases separately).
Spaces and punctuation characters should also be counted.
For example:

For input 'hello world!' it should print:

```
h: 1
e: 1
l: 3
o: 2
    : 1
w: 1
r: 1
d: 1
!: 1
```

For input 'Today it is Tuesday' it should print:

```
t: 3
o: 1
d: 2
a: 2
y: 2
    : 3
i: 2
s: 2
u: 1
e: 1
```

I'm fairly new and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: sounds like homework.

Comment: Since you're new, I should explain that SO isn't really a "here's an assignment, please solve it for me" site.  We're happy to help solve discrete, specific problems you encounter with your code: but you didn't post any code!  As a side note, many of the answers you'll get will make it immediately obvious you didn't write them.  (You should also know that SO questions rate very highly on google-- already searching for many phrases in your question brings this up as the first result.  That may or may not cause difficulties.)

Comment: @DSM I know, I didn't mean for it to turn out that way. I should have specified that I was looking more for guidance, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like homework, in which case `collections.Counter` may not be available and also why it may be worth it to give some guidance instead of answers:

First of all, you need to count the unique values. If you have some input how do you get just unique values?

Answer: use a set.

```
>>> sample = [1, 3, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8]
>>> set(sample)
{8, 1, 3, 6, 7}
# Notice: the order has been thrown away
>>> newsample = 'LollaPAloOza'
>>> set(newsample)
{'a', 'A', 'L', 'l', 'o', 'O', 'z', 'P'}
# Notice: lowercase and uppercase are treated as different characters.
```

New question: how do we treat lowercase and uppercase the same?

Answer: Modify the whole input to make it lowercase or uppercase:

```
>>> set(newsample.lower())
{'a', 'p', 'z', 'l', 'o'}
```

We now have a set of unique values to count. Next problem: how do we count these things?

Answer: we can iterate through the sets (using a for-loop), and then count each item in our set:

```
my_input = newsample.lower()
for item in set(my_input):
      print(my_input.count(item))
# the trick here is to iterate through the unique values and for each element,
# to count the item that appears in the _whole_ (now lowercase) input.
```

Finally, we have to create some data structure to save the items with their counts. A dictionary will be the nice way to do this, or because you need answers in the order they appear, I recommend looking into building a list and associating each count with each item in the list somehow.

However, if you can use it, all of this work is performed by `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 7):

You mention it should be in order, so you can take the `OrderedCounter` recipe from the [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) documentation, eg:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
     'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

     def __repr__(self):
         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

     def __reduce__(self):
         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)

letter_counts = OrderedCounter('hello world!')
# OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 3), ('o', 2), (' ', 1), ('w', 1), ('r', 1), ('d', 1), ('!', 1)]))
```

Then juts loop over that:

```
for letter, count in letter_counts.items():
    print letter, count
```

Comment: +1 nice one, one small remark, I think you should turn string to lower on creation

Comment: @RomanPekar yup - I guess the OP can just do `.lower()` on the string if that's the desired behaviour ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('hello world!')
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, '!': 1, ' ': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1})
```

Didn't notice that you want to preserve the order. For that you can use [OrderedCounter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) example from `collections` module documentation:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> 
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))
...     def __reduce__(self):
...         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
... 
>>> 
>>> count = OrderedCounter('hello world!')
>>> count
OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('l', 3), ('o', 2), (' ', 1), ('w', 1), ('r', 1), ('d', 1), ('!', 1)]))
```

Comment: The output has to be in the order in which the letters appear, but no repeats.

Answer (score 0):

while both answers provide nice examples of OrderedCounter, i still think that it's not a complete answer to question, because new class should count letters turned to lowercase. Sor here's my 2 cents:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
     'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'
     def __init__(self, iterable, **kwds):
         if "lower" in dir(iterable): it = iterable.lower()
         else: it = iterable

         return super(OrderedCounter, self).__init__(it, **kwds)

     def __repr__(self):
         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

     def __reduce__(self):
         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
```

Comment: Umm... Seems overkill putting in a new `__init__`.... Also, you could just try `it = getattr(iterable, 'lower', lambda: iterable)()` ;)

Comment: why is it overkill? is there another way to modify new class such as I don't have to call it like `OrderedCounter("Today is Tuesday!".lower())` and just `OrderedCounter("Today is Tuesday!")`?

Comment: You don't need a new `class` for something as simple as that... Just a custom function will do... `def somename(text): return OrderedCounter(text.lower())` - and if you really wanted to ensure it worked only for strings, then raise an exception if it's not a `basestring` etc...

Comment: well if we've already created a class for the task, I think it bad design not to ensure that all characters are lowered.